# Synergy 1.5 crash (OSX 10.6.8)

Tags: synergy

THANKS FOR TAKING THE TIME TO READ THIS

I recently installed **Synergy 1.5 r2278 (for Mac OSX 10.6.8)** and was using it fine for most of the day, then it decided to stop working (the only thing I changed systemwise was the screensaver - and then after it started crashing disabled it - to see if it would resolve).

When I start Synergy (on the Mac - Client) it says:

after about 5 seconds (and successfully connecting to the Server)

`"synergyc quit unexpectedly"`
Here is the crash log (w/ binery info removed - too long for post requirements)

```
Process:         synergyc [1026]
Path:            /Applications/Synergy.app/Contents/MacOS/synergyc
Identifier:      synergy
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  Synergy [1023]

Date/Time:       2014-05-28 15:36:17.746 +0930
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.8 (10K549)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          2144189 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           23
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  10242 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      86D5A57C-13D4-470E-AC72-48ACDDDE5EB0

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  5

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95cf3afa mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95cf4267 mach_msg + 68
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x95af02df __CFRunLoopRun + 2079
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x95aef3c4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x95aef1f1 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x93654e04 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 392
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x93654bb9 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 354
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x937dd137 ReceiveNextEvent + 83
8   synergyc                        0x000356d0 COSXEventQueueBuffer::waitForEvent(double) + 48
9   synergyc                        0x00010dd5 CEventQueue::getEvent(CEvent&, double) + 325
10  synergyc                        0x00011fb0 CEventQueue::loop() + 272
11  synergyc                        0x00044eb6 CClientApp::mainLoop() + 134
12  synergyc                        0x0005c509 standardStartupStatic(int, char**) + 41
13  synergyc                        0x000448a9 CClientApp::runInner(int, char**, ILogOutputter*, int (*)(int, char**)) + 137
14  synergyc                        0x0005c4b0 CAppUtilUnix::run(int, char**) + 64
15  synergyc                        0x000427df CApp::run(int, char**) + 63
16  synergyc                        0x00006e65 main + 117
17  synergyc                        0x00006dd9 start + 53

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d607da __sigwait + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d607b6 sigwait$UNIX2003 + 71
2   synergyc                        0x00009583 CArchMultithreadPosix::threadSignalHandler(void*) + 67
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d21259 _pthread_start + 345
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d210de thread_start + 34

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d21aa2 __semwait_signal + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d2175e _pthread_cond_wait + 1191
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d212b1 pthread_cond_timedwait$UNIX2003 + 72
3   synergyc                        0x00009476 CArchMultithreadPosix::waitCondVar(CArchCondImpl*, CArchMutexImpl*, double) + 150
4   synergyc                        0x0002b18f CCondVarBase::wait(double) const + 63
5   synergyc                        0x0002ce68 CSocketMultiplexer::serviceThread(void*) + 136
6   synergyc                        0x0002d698 TMethodJob<CSocketMultiplexer>::run() + 40
7   synergyc                        0x0002b8f4 CThread::threadFunc(void*) + 132
8   synergyc                        0x00008f30 CArchMultithreadPosix::doThreadFunc(CArchThreadImpl*) + 80
9   synergyc                        0x0000902a CArchMultithreadPosix::threadFunc(void*) + 74
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d21259 _pthread_start + 345
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d210de thread_start + 34

Thread 3:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d1a382 kevent + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d1aa9c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 215
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d19f59 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 163
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d19cfe _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 240
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d19781 _pthread_wqthread + 390
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d195c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d19412 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d199a8 _pthread_wqthread + 941
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d195c6 start_wqthread + 30

Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d610ee __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d60fd2 nanosleep$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 166
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95ddbfb2 usleep$NOCANCEL$UNIX2003 + 61
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95dfd6f0 abort + 105
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d79b1b _Unwind_Resume + 59
5   synergyc                        0x00008fd1 CArchMultithreadPosix::doThreadFunc(CArchThreadImpl*) + 241
6   synergyc                        0x0000902a CArchMultithreadPosix::threadFunc(void*) + 74
7   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d21259 _pthread_start + 345
8   libSystem.B.dylib               0x95d210de thread_start + 34

Thread 5 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x0000003c  ebx: 0x95d60f39  ecx: 0xb0288a7c  edx: 0x95d610ee
  edi: 0x00521950  esi: 0xb0288ad8  ebp: 0xb0288ab8  esp: 0xb0288a7c
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00000247  eip: 0x95d610ee   cs: 0x00000007
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x0000001f   gs: 0x00000037
  cr2: 0x002fe000
```

Model: **MacBook2,1, BootROM MB21.00A5.B07, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.16 GHz, 2 GB**